# How do I Add Parsing JSON to PHP Script

Tags: php, json

So here's my sample code that I pull from SEOMOZ API for links on a targeted URL.
this script is command line

```
#!/usr/bin/php 
<?php
$objectURL = $domain_url;$accessID = "xyz";
$secretKey = "xya"; 
$expires = mktime() + 300;   
$stringToSign = $accessID."\n".$expires;
$binarySignature = hash_hmac('sha1', $stringToSign, $secretKey, true);
$urlSafeSignature = urlencode(base64_encode($binarySignature));
$urlToFetch = "http://lsapi.seomoz.com/linkscape/links/".urlencode($objectURL)."?AccessID=".$accessID."&Expires=".$expires."&Signature=".$urlSafeSignature."&SourceCols=26&&TargetCols=4&Scope=page_to_domain&Filter=follow&Sort=page_authority&Limit=10";
$handle = fopen($urlToFetch, "r");
$links_contents = '';
while (!feof($handle)) {    
    $links_contents .= fread($handle, 8192);
}
fclose($handle);
echo $links_contents;    
?>
```

the result of the script is that it returns info in JSON format but in a huge glob not in an orderly manner. Whats the easiest way to format the result into a more neater/readable display?

here is the return from JSON

```
{
    "frid": 1,
    "lf": 2,
    "lrid": 3,
    "lsrc": 4,
    "ltgt": 5,
    "luuu": 6,
    "prid": 7,
    "ufq": 8,
    "upl": 9,
    "urid": 10
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You mean `json_decode($links_contents)`?